# RSS feed for votes on user's questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, feed, voting

To make it easier for a user to stay informed about votes on their questions and answers, how about making an RSS feed available which is updated every time someone votes (up or down) on their contributions?

Each RSS update could consist of a link to the question or answer, whether it's an up or down vote, and the reputation change (+10 or -2, or 0 for Community Wiki).

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful having an RSS feed available for anything that would show up in 'users/recent' (i.e. the envelope icon). I frequently click on that to see where the latest +10 came from.  It would also be convenient for being able to click directly to the post that someone has just commented on.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an app that does just that. It's called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) and it works by converting API requests into RSS feeds.

The general format for these feeds looks like:

> `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/`**`{site}`**`/users/`**`{ID}`**`/reputation`

An example that fetches all rep. changes for user #18 on StackApps (me!):

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackapps/users/18/reputation

Comment: It cannot work for me. E.g. `http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/users/103167/reputation`. Please help.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: The tool has moved since I wrote this answer. I have updated the URLs in the answer.

Comment: It's not working now, right? http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com is not available and I see stack2rss's latest commit of on github is 7 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like wanting extra insects to fill the plate.

What's wrong with just bookmarking the **Reputation** tab of your profile and clicking **today** every now and then?

Comment: Nothing. But what's wrong with having a choice?

Comment: Nothing again. Just thinking of a current workaround to the request.

Comment: Nothing except the entire point of RSS in general is to receive updates rather than having to poll for them.